# How do I get this 'Sorted Union' function to work using Array.concat, in javaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am going through this exercise on [FCC](https://www.freecodecamp.com) which requires the following:

> Write a function that takes two or more arrays and returns a new array
>   of unique values in the order of the original provided arrays.
>
> In other words, all values present from all arrays should be included
>   in their original order, but with no duplicates in the final array.
>
> The unique numbers should be sorted by their original order, but the
>   final array should not be sorted in numerical order.

This is my code:

```
function uniteUnique(){

  var elm, exists = {},
      outArr = [], 
      arr = [],
      args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

      args.forEach(function(arg) {
         arr.concat(arg.filter(Boolean));
      });

  for(var i =0; i<arr.length; i++){
    elm = arr[i];
    if(!exists[elm]){
      outArr.push(elm);
      exists[elm] = true;
   }
  }
  return arr;

}
```

My problem centers around this line.

```
      args.forEach(function(arg) {
         arr.concat(arg.filter(Boolean));
      });
```

I'd like all the arguments/arrays to go through the `filter` method and then get concatenated, any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Boolean will not filter unique items, it will simply return `Boolean(arg)` value which is not the intended one.

Replace

```
  args.forEach(function(arg) {
     arr.concat(arg.filter(Boolean));
  });
```

with

```
  args.forEach(function(arg) {
     arr.concat(arg.filter(function(val){
       return arr.indexOf(val) == -1;
     }));
  });
```

This will only concatenate array items which are unique

Comment: Thank you! However, I am getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined(…)` which is something I got back with a similar solution as well...

Comment: @AntonioOrtiz it depend on what argument you are passing to the `uniteUnique` function

Answer (score 1):

Well may be you prefer the following single liner functional approach instead;

```js
var getUniques = (...a) => a.reduce((p,c)=> p.concat(c)).reduce((p,c) => {!~p.indexOf(c) && p.push(c); return p},[]);
document.write("<pre>" + getUniques([1,2,3],[3,4,5],[3,4,5,6,7,8],[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]) + "</pre>");
```

The `getUniques` function returns an array of all uniques in the order of appearance. Note that there is no arguments object in the arrow functions but the `...rest` parameters of ES6 work just as well for that purpose. Even if you don't like the functional approach the logic behind may influence you to implement the same functionality with conventional functions and for loops.

And an even more simplified version of the above one is as follows

```js
var getUniques = (...a) => a.reduce((p,c) => {c.forEach(e => !~p.indexOf(e) && p.push(e)); return p});
document.write("<pre>" + getUniques([1,2,3],[3,4,5],[3,4,5,6,7,8],[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]) + "</pre>");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function union(arrays) {
   const u = arrays.reduce(function(acc, iVal) {
    return acc.concat(iVal);
   })
   return [...new Set(u)];
}

var arr1 = [5, 10, 15];
var arr2 = [15, 88, 1, 5, 7];
var arr3 = [100, 15, 10, 1, 5];
console.log(union([arr1, arr2, arr3])); // should log: [5, 10, 15, 88, 1, 7, 100]
```